# Continuous curve that intersects every open set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I’m looking for necessary and sufficient conditions on the topological space $M$ for existence of a continuous curve (that is, a continuous function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow M$) that intersects any open set of $M$ at least once.

For example, the real line $M = \mathbb{R}$ contains curves with the described above properties. One such curve is given by the identity map.

Comment: Obviously necessary: $M$ is path-connected and separable.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen why is separability a necessary requirement?

Comment: Because the image of this curve $f:\Bbb R \to M$, $f[|\Bbb R]$, is separable and dense, so $M$ is separable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma that makes sense, thanks

Comment: M needn't be path-connected. E.g. Map onto the sine part of the topologists' sine-curve.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent condition is:

> $M$ has a dense subspace $D\subseteq M$ which is a countable union of Peano spaces $D=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} P_i$ such that $P_i\cap P_{i+1}\neq\emptyset$ for each $i\in\mathbb{Z}$.

A Peano space is a space which is metrizable, compact, connected and locally connected. By [the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_theorem) $X$ is a Peano space if and only if $X$ is an image of $[0,1]$.

So lets show that the existence of $f:\mathbb{R}\to M$ such that the image is dense in $M$ (because that's what your condition means) is equivalent to my condition.

"$\Rightarrow$" Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\to M$ is such that $im(f)$ is dense. Let $D=im(f)$ and note that $D=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} f([i,i+1])$ which is the decomposition we are looking for.

"$\Leftarrow$" Assume that $D\subseteq M$ is dense and $D=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} P_i$ where each $P_i$ is a Peano space. Let $\alpha_i:[i,i+1]\to P_i$ be a space filling curve. Since each $P_i$ is path connected and $P_i\cap P_{i+1}\neq\emptyset$, then we can [compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Path_composition) each $\alpha_i$ with some other path in such a way to guarantee that $\alpha_i(i+1)=\alpha_{i+1}(i+1)$. Also note that a composition of two paths is surjective if one of them is surjective. And the rest is simple: we define

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to M$$
$$f(x)=\alpha_{\lfloor x\rfloor}(x)$$

which is continuous by [the infinite variant of the pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma).